# Tkinter canvas does not fill the parent frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do a logical analyzer with a Raspberry Pi, for the GUI I'm doing it with Tkinter. Before adding the scrollbar, I just had a frame at the top like the screenshot, and a canvas down it, here the canvas fill all the space available. But after I decided to add a new frame with two canvas, and now I can't fill the frame with in the space available.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


CH_NAME_WIDTH = 100
N_CHANNELS = 4
SIGNAL_WIDTH = 100
SIGNAL_HEIGHT = 200
SIGNAL_OFFSET = 5

'''

'''
def draw_ch_list(canvas):
  canvas.update()
  canvas.create_line(CH_NAME_WIDTH, 0, CH_NAME_WIDTH, canvas.winfo_height(),     fill='white')
  ch_separator = int(canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS)
  canvas.create_text(CH_NAME_WIDTH / 2, 20, text=f'Channel{1}', fill='green', font=40)

  for h in range(1, N_CHANNELS):
    canvas.create_line(0, ch_separator * h, CH_NAME_WIDTH, ch_separator * h, fill='white')
    canvas.create_text(CH_NAME_WIDTH / 2, 20 + ch_separator * h, text=f'Channel{h+1}', fill='green', font=40)

  canvas.create_text(CH_NAME_WIDTH / 2, 20 + ch_separator * (N_CHANNELS - 1), text=f'Channel{N_CHANNELS}', fill='green', font=40)

'''

'''
def draw_ana(canvas):
  ch_separator = int(canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS)

  for h in range(1, N_CHANNELS):
    canvas.create_line(0, ch_separator * h, canvas.winfo_width(), ch_separator * h, fill='white')

'''

'''
def draw_ch(data, canvas):
  for count, byte in enumerate(data):
   if byte & 1:
     canvas.create_line(SIGNAL_WIDTH * (count + 1), (canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS) - SIGNAL_HEIGHT, SIGNAL_WIDTH * (count + 2), (canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS) - SIGNAL_HEIGHT, fill='red')
   else:
     canvas.create_line(SIGNAL_WIDTH * (count + 1), (canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS) - SIGNAL_OFFSET, SIGNAL_WIDTH * (count + 2), (canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS) - SIGNAL_OFFSET, fill='red')

   if count != 0 and data[count - 1] != data[count]:
     canvas.create_line(SIGNAL_WIDTH * (count + 1), (canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS) - SIGNAL_OFFSET, SIGNAL_WIDTH * (count + 1), (canvas.winfo_height() / N_CHANNELS) - SIGNAL_HEIGHT, fill='red')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('PIAna')
window.geometry(f'{window.winfo_screenwidth()}x{window.winfo_screenheight()}')
window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Header
frm_header = tk.Frame(master=window, bg='white', relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
lbl_triger = tk.Label(master=frm_header, text='Trigger:', font=40)
btn_rising = tk.Button(master=frm_header, text='Rising')
btn_falling = tk.Button(master=frm_header, text='Falling')
lbl_channel = tk.Label(master=frm_header, text='Channel:', font=40)
selected_channel = tk.StringVar()
cb_channel = ttk.Combobox(master=frm_header, textvariable=selected_channel)
cb_channel['values'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
cb_channel['state'] = 'readonly'
lbl_triger.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
btn_rising.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn_falling.grid(row=0, column=2)
lbl_channel.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='nsew')
cb_channel.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nsew')
frm_header.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5)

# Canvas
frm_canvas = tk.Frame(master=window, bg='red')
frm_ana = tk.Frame(master=frm_canvas, bg='green')

canvas_ch = tk.Canvas(master=frm_canvas, bg='black', width=CH_NAME_WIDTH)
canvas_ana = tk.Canvas(master=frm_ana, bg='black')

hbar = tk.Scrollbar(master=frm_ana, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
hbar.config(command=canvas_ana.xview)

canvas_ch.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')

canvas_ana.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set)
canvas_ana.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')
hbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')

frm_ana.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
frm_canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

# draw screen analyzer
draw_ch_list(canvas_ch)
draw_ana(canvas_ana)
draw_ch([1,0,1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ,0 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], canvas_ana)

window.mainloop()
```

If some one has an idea how to fix it.

Comment: There are two canvases. Which one are you asking about? Have you made sure to define row and column weights for every widget that uses grid to manage children?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want both, I did this `window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Comment: You have to do that in every widget that uses grid to manage it's children.